# Error during compiling of a custom module for react native in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, react-native, static-libraries

I am trying to develop a module for `react native` in `swift`, I have followed the tutorial of [Facebook documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html):

All work correctly, but if I put it on `GitHub` and I try to install it in other react native project, when I compile it, I get the follow error:

> "Swift is not supported for static libraries"

[Here](https://github.com/MicheleMola/testdeldestino) is the code of my react-native module.

How can I compile my `react native` app using a `react module` written in `swift`?